# How to use 3 different condition at the same time for disable attribute on Angular 7

Tags: angular, attributes, angular-material, conditional-statements

I have an Angular form.

```
<form class="p-16" name="poMaterialDetailForm [formGroup]="poMaterialDetailForm">
```

Inside the form I have a save button.

```
<button mat-raised-button 
        class="save-poMaterialDetail-button ml-32 mr-8"
        [disabled]="poMaterialDetailForm.invalid || poMaterialDetailForm.pristine"
        <span>SAVE</span>
</button>
```

The disabled attribute allows me to disable the button when there are no changes in the form. If form values are changed then save button becomes active.

I just added a user permission feature and save button is also disabled for users who does not have editing access.

```
<button mat-raised-button
        class="save-clientManagementDetail-button ml-32 mr-8"
        [disabled]="isDisabled('ClientManagement','Edit')"
        *ngIf="pageType ==='edit'" (click)="saveClientManagementDetail()">
    <span>SAVE</span>
</button>
```

Now I want to use both features for disabled attribute. Here is my condition:

```
[disabled]="(clientManagementDetailForm.invalid || clientManagementDetailForm.pristine) 
&& isDisabled('ClientManagement','Edit')"
```

Unfortunately I cannot make this conditions to work. When I use the conditions seperately they work but when I try to use them at the same time, disabled attribute does not change properly accordingly.

Hope the conditions are clear. I would appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this subject.

Cheers,
Johnny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you must change the *AND* to an *OR*:

`(clientManagementDetailForm.invalid || clientManagementDetailForm.pristine)
  || isDisabled('ClientManagement','Edit')`

Because you dont whant the submit button if the form is invalid **OR** the user dont have the editing permission.

Comment: Seconded, and the brackets can be removed from the first condition.

Comment: Yes I agree, but he could leave them there to help with the reading

Comment: Even better, I'd say abstract the whole boolean clause to a suitably named variable, as I'm sure it will be re-used, and it is becoming long.

Comment: @javascript-sucks how can I abstract the whole boolean clause?

Comment: @Johnny you could create a method in your components .ts file which is named somethin like `canSave() ` and in the method you could return the evaluated boolean value, this would make your html more readable because you could just write `[disabled]="canSave()" `

Comment: @Drenai I know what you mean, but i think that the boolean value is evaluated anyways that often so i dont't think it wont make any big difference perfomance wise. Correct me if im wrong